# create Partition is not working in Azure Sql server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to Create Partition in my azure Sql server.
my Sql server version is :- 11.0.9231
and my query is

```
USE [dbName]
GO

-- Create the partition function
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_HASH_BY_VALUE (BIGINT) AS RANGE LEFT 
FOR VALUES (100000, 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 600000, 700000, 800000, 900000)
GO
```

Below is my  error message:-

```
Msg 40510, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Statement 'CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

now on this bloq says it's working with sql server which are later from 2008.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187802.aspx

then why i got error message, can any one give me idea about it.

Regards,
vinit Patel

Comment: What is your sql server edition.is your database on SQL Azure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure SQL Server is not regular SQL Server. There are lots of queries that are not supported in Azure SQL. For example, Cross referencing different database within same Azure SQL server is not supported but was supported in regular SQL Server (or Express edition).

Also, I will advise to upgrade to v12 if it is compatible, as V12 has lot more query support and feature then v11 as you are running.

Comment: ok, but this same query is also not working in my local sql server, my local sql server version is 10.0.2531, in this i got issue is Partition function can only be created in Enterprise edition of SQL Server. Only Enterprise edition of SQL Server supports partitioning.

Comment: I am not sure of which Version support it, but yes I think Express edition might not support it, But if reply is what you get then surely there is nothing anyone can do about it. It is simply not supported. Upgrade to right version :).

Comment: ok let me talk with system admin and update it thank you so much for guideline